# mongodb: remove an object from array

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

i would like to remove a object from an array that matches "market"

my document:

```
{
    _id: "brTuuCYhdcQSsr2xL",
    marketConfig: [
        { market: "de", value: 123 }
        { market: "cn", value: 456 }
    ]
}
```

my javascript code:

```
Database.update(
    { _id: "brTuuCYhdcQSsr2xL" },
    { $pull: { marketConfig: { market: "de" } } },
);
```

after i fire this js code, the document looks like still the same

i am confused... i got no errors messages with this...

Comment: There have been some posts in the past with the only solution being adding a callback function to your query

Comment: and what should i do in the callback?

Comment: Anything should do it... Console.log the result and error, or something along the lines

Comment: in my callback i get no error and the count of matched documents, 1 :/

Answer (score 1):

**Try this,**

```
Database.update(
   { _id: "brTuuCYhdcQSsr2xL" },
   { $pull: { marketConfig: { market: "de" } } },
  false,
  true 
);
```

you have to commit your query by passing the boolean parameters.

Comment: Okay, now i set upsert to false und multi to true. still the same problem :(